# Show block only on "Page Not Found"?

Tags: blocks

Using a Block's visibility setting of *Show block on specific pages: Pages on which this PHP code returns TRUE (experts only)*...

[image]

...what PHP would I write that returns `TRUE` so that the block only shows on "Page Not Found" pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can I recommend not doing it with PHP?

I would suggest making a page (via Admin->Content->Add Content), this assumes that you have the node module installed.

And then set that page as your "Default 404 (not found) page" in Admin->Configuration->System->Site Information

And then you can use that page's path in the block set up, but list under "Only the listed pages"

Comment: That was my first try! Seems simple, right? Doesn't work. When you hit an incorrect URL the Page Not Found page is shown, BUT it doesn't redirect. It retains the incorrect URL. So using its path in the block setup doesn't work… nor does using its node path ("/node/123").

Comment: Instead of adding new node create a panel page. It works! I tried it a month ago!

Comment: Well, I am surprised by that, as drupal_deliver_html_page() https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_deliver_html_page/7.x is called and it sets/executes `menu_set_active_item($path);` and `$return = menu_execute_active_handler($path, FALSE);` using the 404 path you have set in config - and I thought blocks are also invoked from this.  So with your 404 page set, your should be able to do compare your 404 path with  `menu_get_active_trail();` with php

Comment: @rjl Well, you seemed pretty confident that this should work, so I double-checked the path option by adding both the aliased path and the node path to the *Only listed pages* box… and **IT WORKED!** I'm at a loss though; I literally spent an hour on this earlier trying every possible way to make this work using the path, and got nowhere. The only thing I did differently this time is use both path options at the same time… which I don't think has anything to do with it. *Sigh…* must be the Drupal gremlins hard at work again. Anyway, thanks for prompting me to try again!

Comment: I am wondering if those gremlins may have been a caching issue, anyway I am glad it worked!